# How do I make Angular sleep for 5 seconds before navigating to a new page?

Tags: javascript, angular

Quick question, how do I make Angular sleep for 5 seconds before navigating to a new page?

I'm trying this inside my function but it doesn't seem to work:

```
setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('sleep');
      }, 5000);
this.router.navigate(['/question', this.getQuestionID() + 1]);
...
```

Comment: just put the navigation line inside the setTimeout function

Comment: Try placing the navigation line inside of the timeout's callback function.

Comment: Tried this and the answers below, but it doesn't seem to sleep for 5 seconds before navigating...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This happens because `setTimeout` don't block code execution, instead it schedules a callback function execution. That said, your navigate call is outside the callback. This means that it will run right after the callback scheduling, not at it execution.

The right code is:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('sleep');
  this.router.navigate(['/question', this.getQuestionID() + 1]);
  // And any other code that should run only after 5s
}, 5000);
```

*Note:*

If user try to navigate away using some angular router link before tge 5s, it will still run the navigate after 5s causing an strange behavior.

You should neither:

1. Cancel the timeout on route change; or
2. Block the entire page to avoid clicking on any other route.

Comment: What if the user navigates away before those 5s have passed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['/question', this.getQuestionID() + 1]);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 0):

The code that is written inside the `setTimeout(()=>{},5000)` sleeps for 5 sec so try using

```
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('sleep');
    this.router.navigate(['/question', this.getQuestionID() + 1]);
  }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it written in the best way, you should use **RXJS** `timer` operator ([documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer))

```
const subscription = timer(5000).subscribe(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['/question', this.getQuestionID() + 1]);
)};
```

also don't forget to unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook ([documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy))

```
ngOnDestroy() {
   if (this.subscription) {
       this.subscription.unsubscribe();
   }
}
```